# PHP connection to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I had a php code for connection to MySQL

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'testdb';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
?>
```

Every validation data with database I have to type that code such as login, register etc. Let me know if there's another simple way to code that connection on one php file, and every we need a connection, we can just called that file for the connection I need, much appreciate it.

Comment: Add this code in a separate file and `require` that file where you want to create a connection. For more better go for `OOPS` classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a file with name like `connection.php` and put the following code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

and `include` it where required like:

```
include 'connection.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

**File 1:** `mysqlConnection.php`

```
<?php
class mysqlConnection
{
    public static $connection=null;
    public static function connect()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$connection))
        {
            $user = 'root';
            $pass = '';
            $db = 'testdb';

            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
        }
    }
}
```

**File 2:** `test.php`

```
<?php

require_once 'mysqlConnection.php';
mysqlConnection::connect();
//use db connection like this
mysqlConnection::$connection;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
     $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","user_name","password")  //code for connect to MySql
    or die("Couldn't connect to the server");

    $db=mysql_select_db("database_name",$connection)  //code for select a Database
   or die("Couldn't select database");
   ?>
```

Have a great coding buddy!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make a file connection.php or any other file name which is easy for you to remember.

```
<?php
$username = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'DATABASE_NAME_HERE';
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $pass, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

Then include that file on pages you want to use the mysql connection.
You can include that by adding this line on top of that page

```
include_once('connection.php');
```